# Can't install .deb files on VirtualBox VM running Xubuntu

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, xubuntu, virtualization, deb

I've been trying to get a VirtualBox VM set up with Xubuntu on my Windows 10 Home laptop for web development (working through The Odin Project if any of you are familiar with it). However, I can't seem to install any applications from downloaded .deb files. For reference, I've been trying to get Google Chrome and VSCode.

I've tried using the software installer and all the methods listed here:
https://www.ubuntupit.com/cant-install-deb-files-ubuntu-heres-possible-ways-install-deb-packages/
(tl;dr sudo apt install gdebi-core then sudo gdebi _.deb, sudo dpkg -i _.deb, sudo apt install _.deb)

None of those seemed to work. After getting some help, I tried the following:

sudo apt install _.deb
[error message for sudo apt install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO4bw.png)

sudo apt-get install -f then sudo apt install _.deb
[2nd error message for sudo apt install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KpYR.png)

sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade then the same commands from before
[sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWPnl.png)
[3rd error message for sudo apt install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIn4q.png)

Sorry if the images are difficult to read. I don't have the original terminal output anymore, so those are the screenshots of error messages I sent while getting help.

At this point, I'm at a loss for what I should do. It took me ~15 tries of uninstalling and reinstalling Virtual Box and Xubuntu to get the VM up and running, so maybe this installation isn't functional either? I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Next time, copy/paste the error messages into a text editor to preserve them (if your VM is set up properly, you can do that). While doing that, take a moment to read the error messages line-by-line. The developers intended that output to help users troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: You don't install downloaded .deb files with apt. You install them with dkpg. Like this sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb Or even better, gdebi which will handle the dependencies.

Comment: @user535733 Will do that next time, thanks for the advice. I did read the error messages carefully, but I didn't have the foresight to copy/paste the them.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I did try that (mentioned it in the post), but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for the help, but I ended up getting it working by giving the VM installation a few more tries. I did already try sudo dpkg -i though, which I think is the only installation method mentioned in that thread.

Answer (score 1):

Download the package again.

The message is clear: **compressed data is corrupt**

Comment: Already attempted that a few times, but thanks for the suggestion. I ended up giving the VM installation a few more tries and got it working.